# Dialing a network service number like #100*3# by AT Command

Tags: c#, at-command

How to dial a network service number like #100*3# by AT Command? And what is the correct syntax in C# because when I try to dial it, the application considers it as a phone number and I hear  a message that means that I can't dial this number.

Note: the code is successfully running and I can successfully dial any phone number but the problem is in the network service numbers.

I tried the following code:

```
sp.WriteLine("AT+CUSD=1,#"+100+"*3#,15"+Environment.NewLine );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for the `AT+CUSD` command is specified in [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm):

```
AT+CUSD=[<n>[,<str>[,<dcs>]]]
```

and the `<str>` parameter is a string which **must** be enclosed in double quotes. From [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en):

> String constants shall be bounded at the beginning and end by the double-quote character

So your code should be

```
sp.WriteLine("AT+CUSD=1,\"#100*3#\",15\r");
```

Update: You should never use Environment.NewLine to terminate the command line, it should just be `\r` always.

Comment: Firstly thanks because the code is approximately working, but the problem is that the code is only responding to the first part of the code.I mean that #100# is the same result like #100*3# what means that it doesn't look at 3 . finally i want ,for example, to write #100*3*1*5*01287687678# because by writing it like  the upper code the result will be like writing just #100#

Comment: by the way I tried the following codes but they don't work::             sp.WriteLine"ATCUSD=1,"#100*0000\",15"Environment.NewLine);
sp.WriteLine("AT+CUSD=1,\"1\",15" + Environment.NewLine);           and also                                                           AT+CUSD=1,"#100*0000\"
AT+CUSD=1,"1"